# Vuejs wont render shopping cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get a shopping cart in my navbar, but for some reason it is not rendering in it. I do not understand why since I am new to vue.js, but I do not find any error...

Here you find the **CartSummary.vue**

```
<template>
<b-nav-item id="Cart" to="/cart">
 <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  Cart ({{ count }})
 <b-popover target="Cart" triggers="hover">
   <div>
     Items: {{ count }}
   </div>
   <div>
     Total: {{ total | currency }}
   </div>
 </b-popover>
</b-nav-item>
```

```
<script>
export default {
 name: "cart-summary",
 computed: {
   total() {
      return this.$store.getters.shoppingCartTotal;
   },
   count() {
      return this.$store.getters.shoppingCartItemCount;
  }
 }
};
</script>
```

And this is the **App.vue** which is rendering perfectly except the cart. I import the carsummary.vue and import it in the template, but it does not show.

```
<template>
<div class="app">
<b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="dark">
  <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
  <b-navbar-brand to="/">Shop</b-navbar-brand>
  <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">
    <b-navbar-nav>
      <b-nav-item to="/products">Products</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>
    <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto mr-4">
      <auth-nav-item/>
      <cart-summary>
      </cart-summary>

    </b-navbar-nav>
  </b-collapse>
</b-navbar>
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <router-view />
</transition>
<auth-modal :show="showAuthModal" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import AuthNavItem from "./app/AuthNavItem.vue";
import AuthModal from "./app/AuthModal.vue";
import CartSummary from "./cart/CartSummary.vue";

export default {
 name: "app",
  components: { 
    CartSummary,
    AuthNavItem,
    AuthModal,
  },
   computed: {
     showAuthModal() {
     return this.$store.state.showAuthModal;
  }
 },
   beforeCreate() {
   this.$store.commit("initialise");
 }
};
</script>
```

I think this is where the problem is, but if you need more info, feel free to ask.

Thank you for the effort guys. 
Kind regards!

EDIT 
**getters.js**

```
export const shoppingCartTotal = state => {
const reducer = (accumulator, cartItem) =>
  accumulator + cartItem.price * cartItem.quantity;

return state.cart.reduce(reducer, 0);
};

export const shoppingCartItemCount = state => {
const reducer = (accumulator, cartItem) => accumulator + cartItem.quantity;
return state.cart.reduce(reducer, 0);
};
```

Comment: the first guess is that component name in cartsummary.vue should be 'cartSummary'

Comment: Is your component file name "cartsummary.vue"  or "CartSummary.vue"   because up top you only have all lower case.

Comment: The filename is CartSummary.vue like the imports. @skribe

Comment: Looks like a problem with your store, then. Can we see what your store looks like?

Comment: @JudeDesir I think you are right, the cart appears when I delete the {{ count }} and {{ total }}, I edited the post, the getters are at the bottom.